# how to link separate css files to aspx files

Tags: asp.net

I've inherited an .net 4 aspx solution and I need to make a number of changes. All the styles in the main seem to be set in-line. So to make it a bit more maintainable I'm trying to create seperate css files for each aspx file. This may seem overkill, but it's a first stage of gradually moving over to .net core.

Ordinarily I'd simply do something like:

```
<asp:Content......
  <link href="myStyleSheet"....
</asp:Content>
```

but the link statement causes an error stating that it cannot be nested within a td element. Placing it outside the content block also errors stating that Content is not supported outside the content block.

How should I reference my stylesheets on an individual basis without placing a reference to them all in the `<head>` section of the master page?

Comment: "I've inherited an .net 4 aspx solution" - you have my sympathy

Comment: "but the link statement causes an error stating that it cannot be nested within a td element." - `<link>` elements go in the `<head>` - why are you adding it to a table cell!??!

Comment: "How should I reference my stylesheets on an individual basis without placing a reference to them all in the <head> section of the master page?" - **you don't and you can't**

Comment: @Dai  from the aspx page, it's not obvious that it's in a <td> element. On one particular aspx page ofr instance inside the content block there is a div element followed by an asp panel nothing about a table.

Answer (score 0):

> the link statement causes an error stating that it cannot be nested within a td element

Well, that's true.  You don't put `<link>` elements *inside a table*.  [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) they can go in "Any element that accepts metadata elements."  `<td>` definitely is not such an element.  `<head>` certainly is, and is probably the safest place to put these.

In your master page you can add a `ContentPlaceHolder` in the `<head>`:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Your page title</title>
    <!-- etc. -->
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="HeaderPlaceholder" runat="server" />
</head>
```

Then in the individual pages put the `<link>` elements in a `Content` control for that placeholder:

```
<asp:Content ID="ContentHeader" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeaderPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <link href="myStyleSheet" etc... />
</asp:Content>
```

> This may seem overkill

Ya, it kinda does.  Why a separate stylesheet *for each page*?  Seems like it would make more sense to have one stylesheet *for the site*.  For any styling that needs to target only a specific page and nothing else, some wrapper element around that page's content (such as a `<div>`) with a specific `id` will make that easy.

Comment: Can I have an <asp:content element inside another <asp:content element  on the same aspx page. so that I can remove the inline css currently inside the asp:content block to the css page. Reason for separate css files , plan on creating a .net core solution using Angular. so by separating  styles out now will mean an easier port for the css later.

Comment: @bilpor: I don't know if you can nest `Content` controls like that, but you can try.  Though I can't imagine why you'd want to.  Just reference the stylesheet in the header and have the page content in the body.  Once your stylesheet is successfully referenced then you can remove the inline styles.